# A run-time error prevent my to-do application to start

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

This is what I found in the LogCat:

```
02-26 05:10:44.943: E/AndroidRuntime(844): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-26 05:10:44.943: E/AndroidRuntime(844): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{course.labs.todomanager/course.labs.todomanager.ToDoManagerActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060013 type #0x12 is not valid
02-26 05:10:44.943: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
02-26 05:10:44.943: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
02-26 05:10:44.943: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-26 05:10:44.943: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
02-26 05:10:44.943: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-26 05:10:44.943: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-26 05:10:44.943: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-26 05:10:44.943: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 05:10:44.943: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-26 05:10:44.943: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-26 05:10:44.943: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-26 05:10:44.943: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-26 05:10:44.943: E/AndroidRuntime(844): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060013 type #0x12 is not valid
02-26 05:10:44.943: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2309)
02-26 05:10:44.943: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:934)
02-26 05:10:44.943: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:395)
02-26 05:10:44.943: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
02-26 05:10:44.943: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at course.labs.todomanager.ToDoManagerActivity.onCreate(ToDoManagerActivity.java:56)
02-26 05:10:44.943: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
02-26 05:10:44.943: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-26 05:10:44.943: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
02-26 05:10:44.943: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  ... 11 more
```

The Applicaion is a to-do app and it has 4 activities as follows:

**1- ToDoManagerActivity**

```
        package course.labs.todomanager;

        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.BufferedWriter;
        import java.io.FileInputStream;
        import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
        import java.io.FileOutputStream;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
        import java.io.PrintWriter;
        import java.text.ParseException;
        import java.util.Date;

        import android.app.ListActivity;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import course.labs.todomanager.ToDoItem.Priority;
        import course.labs.todomanager.ToDoItem.Status;

        public class ToDoManagerActivity extends ListActivity {

            // Add a ToDoItem Request Code
            private static final int ADD_TODO_ITEM_REQUEST = 0;

            private static final String FILE_NAME = "TodoManagerActivityData.txt";
            private static final String TAG = "Lab-UserInterface";

            // IDs for menu items
            private static final int MENU_DELETE = Menu.FIRST;
            private static final int MENU_DUMP = Menu.FIRST + 1;

            ToDoListAdapter mAdapter;

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                // Create a new TodoListAdapter for this ListActivity's ListView
                mAdapter = new ToDoListAdapter(getApplicationContext());

                // Put divider between ToDoItems and FooterView
                getListView().setFooterDividersEnabled(true);

                //TODO - Inflate footerView for footer_view.xml file
                TextView footerView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.footerView);
    LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
    li.inflate(R.id.footerView, getListView());


                //TODO - Add footerView to ListView

                ListView lv = getListView();
                lv.addFooterView(footerView);

                footerView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        log("Entered footerView.OnClickListener.onClick()");

                        //TODO - Attach Listener to FooterView. Implement onClick().
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ToDoManagerActivity.this, AddToDoActivity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_TODO_ITEM_REQUEST);
                    }
                });

                //TODO - Attach the adapter to this ListActivity's ListView
                lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

                log("Entered onActivityResult()");

                // TODO - Check result code and request code.
                // If user submitted a new ToDoItem
                // Create a new ToDoItem from the data Intent
                // and then add it to the adapter

                if (requestCode == ADD_TODO_ITEM_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                {
                    ToDoItem toDoItem = new ToDoItem(data);
                    mAdapter.add(toDoItem);
                }
            }

            // Do not modify below here

            @Override
            public void onResume() {
                super.onResume();

                // Load saved ToDoItems, if necessary

                if (mAdapter.getCount() == 0)
                    loadItems();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPause() {
                super.onPause();

                // Save ToDoItems

                saveItems();

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

                menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_DELETE, Menu.NONE, "Delete all");
                menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_DUMP, Menu.NONE, "Dump to log");
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case MENU_DELETE:
                    mAdapter.clear();
                    return true;
                case MENU_DUMP:
                    dump();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
                }
            }

            private void dump() {

                for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    String data = ((ToDoItem) mAdapter.getItem(i)).toLog();
                    log("Item " + i + ": " + data.replace(ToDoItem.ITEM_SEP, ","));
                }

            }

            // Load stored ToDoItems
            private void loadItems() {
                BufferedReader reader = null;
                try {
                    FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(FILE_NAME);
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

                    String title = null;
                    String priority = null;
                    String status = null;
                    Date date = null;

                    while (null != (title = reader.readLine())) {
                        priority = reader.readLine();
                        status = reader.readLine();
                        date = ToDoItem.FORMAT.parse(reader.readLine());
                        mAdapter.add(new ToDoItem(title, Priority.valueOf(priority),
                                Status.valueOf(status), date));
                    }

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (null != reader) {
                        try {
                            reader.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Save ToDoItems to file
            private void saveItems() {
                PrintWriter writer = null;
                try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
                    writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                            fos)));

                    for (int idx = 0; idx < mAdapter.getCount(); idx++) {

                        writer.println(mAdapter.getItem(idx));

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (null != writer) {
                        writer.close();
                    }
                }
            }

            private void log(String msg) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.i(TAG, msg);
            }

        }
```

**2- ToDoListAdapter:**
        package course.labs.todomanager;

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.CheckBox;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import course.labs.todomanager.ToDoItem.Status;

    public class ToDoListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        // List of ToDoItems
        private final List<ToDoItem> mItems = new ArrayList<ToDoItem>();

        private final Context mContext;

        private static final String TAG = "Lab-UserInterface";

        public ToDoListAdapter(Context context) {

            mContext = context;

        }

        // Add a ToDoItem to the adapter
        // Notify observers that the data set has changed

        public void add(ToDoItem item) {

            mItems.add(item);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        // Clears the list adapter of all items.

        public void clear(){

            mItems.clear();
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        // Returns the number of ToDoItems

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return mItems.size();

        }

        // Retrieve the number of ToDoItems

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int pos) {

            return mItems.get(pos);

        }

        // Get the ID for the ToDoItem
        // In this case it's just the position

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int pos) {

            return pos;

        }

        //Create a View to display the ToDoItem 
        // at specified position in mItems

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            //TODO - Get the current ToDoItem
            final ToDoItem toDoItem = (ToDoItem) getItem(position);

            //TODO - Inflate the View for this ToDoItem
            // from todo_item.xml.
            RelativeLayout itemLayout = (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.todo_item, parent);

            //TODO - Fill in specific ToDoItem data
            // Remember that the data that goes in this View
            // corresponds to the user interface elements defined 
            // in the layout file 



            //TODO - Display Title in TextView

            final TextView titleView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleView);
            titleView.setText(toDoItem.getTitle());

            // TODO - Set up Status CheckBox

            final CheckBox statusView = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusCheckBox);


            statusView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    log("Entered onCheckedChanged()");

                    // TODO - Set up and implement an OnCheckedChangeListener, which 
                    // is called when the user toggles the status checkbox

                    if(isChecked)
                    {
                        toDoItem.setStatus(Status.DONE);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        toDoItem.setStatus(Status.NOTDONE);
                    }

                }
            });

            //TODO - Display Priority in a TextView

            final TextView priorityView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.priorityView);
            priorityView.setTag(toDoItem.getPriority());


            // TODO - Display Time and Date. 
            // Hint - use ToDoItem.FORMAT.format(toDoItem.getDate()) to get date and time String

            final TextView dateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateView);
            dateView.setText(ToDoItem.FORMAT.format(toDoItem.getDate()));

            // Return the View you just created
            return itemLayout;

        }

        private void log(String msg) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i(TAG, msg);
        }

    }
```

**3- AddToDoActivity**
        package course.labs.todomanager;

```
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Date;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.app.DialogFragment;
    import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.DatePicker;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.TimePicker;
    import course.labs.todomanager.ToDoItem.Priority;
    import course.labs.todomanager.ToDoItem.Status;

    public class AddToDoActivity extends Activity {

        // 7 days in milliseconds - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
        private static final int SEVEN_DAYS = 604800000;

        private static final String TAG = "Lab-UserInterface";

        private static String timeString;
        private static String dateString;
        private static TextView dateView;
        private static TextView timeView;


        private Date mDate;
        private RadioGroup mPriorityRadioGroup;
        private RadioGroup mStatusRadioGroup;
        private EditText mTitleText;
        private RadioButton mDefaultStatusButton;
        private RadioButton mDefaultPriorityButton;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.add_todo);

            mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
            mDefaultStatusButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.statusNotDone);
            mDefaultPriorityButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.medPriority);
            mPriorityRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.priorityGroup);
            mStatusRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.statusGroup);
            dateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
            timeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);

            // Set the default date and time

            setDefaultDateTime();

            // OnClickListener for the Date button, calls showDatePickerDialog() to show
            // the Date dialog

            final Button datePickerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.date_picker_button);
            datePickerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showDatePickerDialog();
                }
            });

            // OnClickListener for the Time button, calls showTimePickerDialog() to show
            // the Time Dialog

            final Button timePickerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.time_picker_button);
            timePickerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showTimePickerDialog();
                }
            });

            // OnClickListener for the Cancel Button, 

            final Button cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
            cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    log("Entered cancelButton.OnClickListener.onClick()");

                    //TODO - Implement onClick().  
                    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
                    finish();
                }
            });

            //OnClickListener for the Reset Button

            final Button resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
            resetButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    log("Entered resetButton.OnClickListener.onClick()");

                    //TODO - Reset data fields to default values

                    mTitleText.setText(R.id.title);
                    mPriorityRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.priorityGroup);
                    mStatusRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.statusGroup);
                    setDefaultDateTime();



                }
            });

            // OnClickListener for the Submit Button
            // Implement onClick().

            final Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
            submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    log("Entered submitButton.OnClickListener.onClick()");

                    // Gather ToDoItem data  

                    //TODO - Get Priority
                    Priority priority = getPriority();

                    //TODO -  Get Status
                    Status status = getStatus();

                    //TODO -  Title
                    String titleString = mTitleText.getPrivateImeOptions();

                    // Date
                    String fullDate = dateString + " " + timeString;

                    // Package ToDoItem data into an Intent
                    Intent data = new Intent();
                    ToDoItem.packageIntent(data, titleString, priority, status, fullDate);

                    //TODO - return data Intent and finish

                    setResult(RESULT_OK);
                    finish();


                }
            });
        }

        // Do not modify below here

        // Use this method to set the default date and time

        private void setDefaultDateTime() {

            // Default is current time + 7 days
            mDate = new Date();
            mDate = new Date(mDate.getTime() + SEVEN_DAYS);

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTime(mDate);

            setDateString(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

            dateView.setText(dateString);

            setTimeString(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                    c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

            timeView.setText(timeString);
        }

        private static void setDateString(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

            // Increment monthOfYear for Calendar/Date -> Time Format setting
            monthOfYear++;
            String mon = "" + monthOfYear;
            String day = "" + dayOfMonth;

            if (monthOfYear < 10)
                mon = "0" + monthOfYear;
            if (dayOfMonth < 10)
                day = "0" + dayOfMonth;

            dateString = year + "-" + mon + "-" + day;
        }

        private static void setTimeString(int hourOfDay, int minute, int mili) {
            String hour = "" + hourOfDay;
            String min = "" + minute;

            if (hourOfDay < 10)
                hour = "0" + hourOfDay;
            if (minute < 10)
                min = "0" + minute;

            timeString = hour + ":" + min + ":00";
        }

        private Priority getPriority() {

            switch (mPriorityRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
            case R.id.lowPriority: {
                return Priority.LOW;
            }
            case R.id.highPriority: {
                return Priority.HIGH;
            }
            default: {
                return Priority.MED;
            }
            }
        }

        private Status getStatus() {

            switch (mStatusRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
            case R.id.statusDone: {
                return Status.DONE;
            }
            default: {
                return Status.NOTDONE;
            }
            }
        }

        // DialogFragment used to pick a ToDoItem deadline date

        public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
                DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

            @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                // Use the current date as the default date in the picker

                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
                return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                    int dayOfMonth) {
                setDateString(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

                dateView.setText(dateString);
            }

        }

        // DialogFragment used to pick a ToDoItem deadline time

        public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
                TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

            @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return
                return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                        true);
            }

            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                setTimeString(hourOfDay, minute, 0);

                timeView.setText(timeString);
            }
        }

        private void showDatePickerDialog() {
            DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
        }

        private void showTimePickerDialog() {
            DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
        }

        private void log(String msg) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i(TAG, msg);
        }

    }
```

**4- ToDoItem**

```
    package course.labs.todomanager;

    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.Locale;

    import android.content.Intent;

    // Do not modify 

    public class ToDoItem {

        public static final String ITEM_SEP = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        public enum Priority {
            LOW, MED, HIGH
        };

        public enum Status {
            NOTDONE, DONE
        };

        public final static String TITLE = "title";
        public final static String PRIORITY = "priority";
        public final static String STATUS = "status";
        public final static String DATE = "date";
        public final static String FILENAME = "filename";

        public final static SimpleDateFormat FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);

        private String mTitle = new String();
        private Priority mPriority = Priority.LOW;
        private Status mStatus = Status.NOTDONE;
        private Date mDate = new Date();

        ToDoItem(String title, Priority priority, Status status, Date date) {
            this.mTitle = title;
            this.mPriority = priority;
            this.mStatus = status;
            this.mDate = date;
        }

        // Create a new ToDoItem from data packaged in an Intent

        ToDoItem(Intent intent) {

            mTitle = intent.getStringExtra(ToDoItem.TITLE);
            mPriority = Priority.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra(ToDoItem.PRIORITY));
            mStatus = Status.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra(ToDoItem.STATUS));

            try {
                mDate = ToDoItem.FORMAT.parse(intent.getStringExtra(ToDoItem.DATE));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                mDate = new Date();
            }
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return mTitle;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            mTitle = title;
        }

        public Priority getPriority() {
            return mPriority;
        }

        public void setPriority(Priority priority) {
            mPriority = priority;
        }

        public Status getStatus() {
            return mStatus;
        }

        public void setStatus(Status status) {
            mStatus = status;
        }

        public Date getDate() {
            return mDate;
        }

        public void setDate(Date date) {
            mDate = date;
        }

        // Take a set of String data values and 
        // package them for transport in an Intent

        public static void packageIntent(Intent intent, String title,
                Priority priority, Status status, String date) {

            intent.putExtra(ToDoItem.TITLE, title);
            intent.putExtra(ToDoItem.PRIORITY, priority.toString());
            intent.putExtra(ToDoItem.STATUS, status.toString());
            intent.putExtra(ToDoItem.DATE, date);

        }

        public String toString() {
            return mTitle + ITEM_SEP + mPriority + ITEM_SEP + mStatus + ITEM_SEP
                    + FORMAT.format(mDate);
        }

        public String toLog() {
            return "Title:" + mTitle + ITEM_SEP + "Priority:" + mPriority
                    + ITEM_SEP + "Status:" + mStatus + ITEM_SEP + "Date:"
                    + FORMAT.format(mDate);
        }

    }
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Goto R.java there search - "0x7f060013 ". Then get the resource which the AndroidRuntime is unable to find.. Check if it exists

Answer (score 4):

```
li.inflate(R.id.footerView, getListView());
```

You cannot inflate `id`s, only `layout`s.

Replace `R.id.footerView` with `R.layout.your_footer_view_layout`.

Also, you probably want to capture the inflated `View` to some variable to actually use it later.

Comment: Thanks, I do appreciate your answer :)
However I still get the error :/

Comment: Likely a different error with different stacktrace?

Comment: No :(
it is the same log
actually it is broken before the app starts

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
//Inflate footerView for footer_view.xml file

TextView footerView = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `setTag()`. Change

```
priorityView.setTag(toDoItem.getPriority());
```

to

```
priorityView.setText(toDoItem.getPriority().ToString());
```